# Swift Protocol using associated types and Self?

Tags: swift

Given this protocol:

```
protocol SomeProtocol { 
    associatedtype MyCustomType

    static func someCustomStaticFunction(with customTypeData: MyCustomType) -> Self?
}
```

why does this:

```
extension MyClass: SomeProtocol {
    static func someCustomStaticFunction(with customTypeData: MyCustomType) -> Self? {
        return MyClass()
    }
}
```

not compile? The error is: `cannot convert return expression of type 'MyClass" to return type "Self?`. Why in the heck doesn't this work? If it doesn't, whats the point of even using Swift in the first place? If I can't build type-safe protocols and I'm forced to type-erase it all anyway, what's the point? Can someone help me out?

EDIT:

the issue was not the associated type, it was return `Self?`

Comment: You need to make `MyClass` final and change the `Self` returned in `MyClass` extension to `MyClass`

Comment: Maybe make a required initializer part of the protocol and call that so Self is returned despite MyClass being derived.

Comment: That worked @ukim! You can post that answer an answer and I'll accept. If you know why that's the case and could provide an explanation, that'd be great too :)

Comment: It seems the problem does not related to associated type. You may edit the question if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `MyClass` final and replace the `Self` returned in `MyClass` extension with `MyClass`.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    static func someCustomStaticFunction() -> Self?
}

final class MyClass {

}

extension MyClass: SomeProtocol {
    static func someCustomStaticFunction() -> MyClass? {
        return MyClass()
    }
}
```

1. We can only use `Self` in protocol but not class extension.
2. You need to make `MyClass` final. If not, let's say you have a sub class called `MySubclass`, it must also confirm to `SomeProtocol` as its parent. So `MySubclass` must have `someCustomStaticFunction() -> MySubclass`. However, `MyClass` already has this function implemented but with different return type. Swift does not support overload return type at the moment, as a result, we must not subclass `MyClass`, this is make it final.